# Reading from uart

Tags: linux, gps, kernel, pyserial, uart

I am using am57x micro-controller and plugged my ublox neo-m8n gps to UART6. After putting uart6 in device tree as shown below, how can I know which file to read from? i couldn't find anything in /sys/class/.. how do i know which tty file the gps is writing to? Are there any uart native commands like the iscdetect and i2cget for i2c? Any help is appreciated

From dra7.dtsi:

```
uart6: serial@48068000 {
        compatible = "ti,dra742-uart", "ti,omap4-uart";
        reg = <0x48068000 0x100>;
        interrupts = <GIC_SPI 101 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
        ti,hwmods = "uart6";
        clock-frequency = <48000000>;
        status = "disabled";
        dmas = <&sdma_xbar 79>, <&sdma_xbar 80>;
        dma-names = "tx", "rx";
    };
```

From my device tree:

```
&uart6 {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&uart6_pins_default>;
    status = "okay";
};
```

Comment: Simple use an existing GNSS driver for you device. DT defines the link to the UART controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, after a lot of trial, I found out that it was writing to /dev/ttyS5. The link below helped me figure it out:
https://www.technexion.com/support/knowledgebase/using-a-serial-port-from-a-linux-shell/

Answer (score 0):

If you are running linux and your serial device is detected by the kernel. It will print the message in the kernel log buffer where the device is attached.

If the device is not showing in /sys/class check the kernel logs using "dmesg" command after inserting the module. It will show error if kernel not able detect your device properly.